# Элементы в одну строку

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, плизз, я в HTML не очень шарю, нужен тег типа присоединения или пробела (чтобы было в одной строке) вот так

[image: снимок]

А то у меня вот так выглядит

[image: снимок]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вот готовое решение: [Блок «Поделиться»][1].


  [1]: http://api.yandex.ru/share/

Comment: Напишите хотябы код а не тупо картинками...

Answer (score 3):

html:

```
<div class="social">
   <div class="vk"><!--здесь код кнопки--></div>
   <div class="mail"><!--здесь код кнопки--></div>
   <div class="ok"><!--здесь код кнопки--></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.vk,.ok,.mail{float:left;margin:0 10px;}
```

Comment: Если кнопки без счетчиков то абсолютно правильное решение

Comment: какая разница, счётчики или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `display: inline-block` для элементов.

Answer (score 1):

Пример расположения элементов в одну строку:

```css
.box div { width:90px; display:inline-block; }
```

```html
  <div class="box">
    <div>#1 Первый</div>
    <div>#2 Второй</div>
    <div>#3 Третий</div>
  </div>
```

> `display` - многоцелевое свойство, которое определяет, как элемент
>   должен быть показан в документе. Значение `inline-block` - генерирует
>   блочный элемент, который обтекается другими элементами веб-страницы
>   подобно строчному элементу.

Comment: Кто-то фармит некроманта =)

Answer (score 0):

пробел можно использовать alt+0160(на нумпаде) вопрос в том, как ты их размещаешь... код выложи, посмотрим, что с ними сделать)

Comment: если вы так каждый раз пишете пробел, мне вас жаль. используйте <pre>&nbsp;</pre>